# TFJS-converter | How can I convert faster_cnn_inception_v2_coco to tfjs format?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

While I am trying to convert faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco saved model to Javascript format, I received an issue:

`KeyError: <tf.Tensor 'SecondStagePostprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppresion/map/while/Switch_1:0' shape=<unkknown> dtype=float32>`

Environment:
python3.6 , tensorflowjs 1.0.1, MacOS Mojave 10.14.3

Steps to reproduce:

1. Download [faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28.tar.gz) tar and extract it
2. Try to convert with

```
 tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=tf_saved_model --output_format=tfjs_graph_model <pathToExtractedTar>/saved_model ./output_folder
```

Would you be so kind to suggest some ideas according this issue?

Thank you

Comment: I am able to replicate this issue on my own workstation.  I suspect that there is some property of the input model that is not handled by the converter, and that the error message does not accurately reflect the actual problem.